# Converting my jQuery animations to CSS3 transitions — "proper" methods / handling variables?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm on my first big website project (although it is still personal, in the sense that it is my portfolio website, and not for a client). I'm most of the way done, and have learnt a lot of the course of doing it.

The majority of animations and other things changing and moving around on the site is currently done using jQuery animations. However, it has come to my attention today that using CSS3 transitions is probably the much better, more efficient, and nicer way to do things!

As such I'm in the process of changing a bunch of my jQuery animations over to CSS3 transitions, and it's gone mostly smooth. I do have a few question about proper methods, however.

## Example 1

For example, what is the best way to handle a transition that needs to occur when certain variables in JS are set? Is there a way to pass these variables to the CSS, or do I use jQ to tell it "when true, add these transition properties to the CSS", in order to trigger the animation?

Eg:

An element must change it's height. The height it will change to is different depending on the screen width - this is handled with media queries. BUT, the height should only change if `xyz = true`, other wise, it should stay the same. How can CSS know whether or not `xyz` is true?

## Example 2

`#header` is set to a certain height using media queries that determine the page width. When `xyz = true`, `#header`'s height should now animate down to 0. When `xyz = false` `#header` should return to it's initial height (as defined by media queries).

The problem here is that by setting CSS transitions in place to animate `#header` to 0, that has now become part of the element's style, and "0" will override the values give by trying to return it to initial.

This problem is tackled in CSS with selectors (I believe that's what they're called? Things such as `:hover` and `:click`.)—when they are used, they are not overriding the element's style, and so they can return to initial properly. But here, there are no selectors for when `xyz = true`. We have to set the values in jQuery, which are now overriding the possibility of returning to initial.

## Problem

How can these examples be combated? They are both somewhat asking the same question; Is there a way to pass CSS the variables for when something is true, or a way to create a selector of sorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "correct" method to do things. However, using CSS transitions/animations doesn't mean you have to avoid javascript logic.

For example, lets say you wanted to change the colour of an element based on some logic. Instead of using `.animate()` or `.css()` to set the value in jQuery, you could set up the following css classes:

```
.element {
    color: red;
    transition: color 300ms;
}

.element.active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then in jQuery, you could do the following:

```
if ( condition )
    $('.element').addClass('active');
else
    $('.element').removeClass('active');
```

You can use this method on any animatable CSS property, you just need to have the correct transition set on the element. Javascript contains the logic and applies the relevant classes, and CSS handles the transitions.

If, on the rare condition that you need to use specific values that you can only retrieve with Javascript (eg, computed values), you can still use CSS to animate those properties. For example, if you wanted to animate the width of an element to a specific value. In your CSS, you may have this:

```
.element {
    width: 200px;
    transition: width 300ms;
}
```

And in your javascript, you could do this:

```
if ( condition )
    $('.element').width('400px');
else
    $('.element').width('');
```

As a rule of thumb, you should only use this method if the values are computed. If the values are static, you should use the first method of toggling classes.

Comment: I see... I'm still in the process of learning about CSS transitions here: so as long as there's a transition applying to a certain property in a style, whenever that property of something with that style changes, it will transition?

Comment: @GtwoK Yeah that's correct. I updated my answer to explain this a bit better, the `display block/none` example was a bad example because you can't actually animate the `display` property.

Comment: I've already marked this as answered, but what if I would like to simply change css value, without transitioning it? The value I am changing it to is computed, so I will need JS to do it. Is it simply a matter of making the transition duration 0s? I don't know the internals, but that seems like it would take extra processing power to do than a method to simply change it. jQuery's `.css()` is not an option, because that would override the values.

Comment: @GtwoK Properties don't animate by default so that shouldn't be an issue; setting the duration to 0 does nothing if there wasn't a transition to start with. If you want to override a transition, use `transition: none`. If the value is computed, you **must** use `.css()`. There is no other way to change the value, unless you go down the complex route of dynamically generating classes with JS (which is unnecessary). If you want to change the value, then I don't see why overriding is an issue - perhaps you'll need to provide a specific example of the problem you're facing, then we can help you.